# Duplicate entry when update in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

when i inserting 1 record in tb_penerimaan when I display it, 1 record appears

```
 MariaDB [sijarvis]> SELECT tb_penerimaan.* , tb_pelanggan.nama FROM tb_penerimaan, tb_pelanggan;
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-------------+------+-----------+----------------+-------+------------+-------+
| no_servis   | tgl_terima | kode_pelanggan | nama_perangkat | model_perangkat | no_model | keluhan    | kelengkapan | dp   | status    | solusi         | harga | presentase | nama  |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-------------+------+-----------+----------------+-------+------------+-------+
| SER00000001 | 2019-01-31 | PE000001       | ASUS           | X453SA          | CVT122   | gsdggfddfg | dfgfgd      | 5000 | Di Servis | Belum Diservis |     0 | 15         | Anggi |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-------------+------+-----------+----------------+-------+------------+-------+
```

and insert more record showed up

```
MariaDB [sijarvis]> SELECT tb_penerimaan.* , tb_pelanggan.nama FROM tb_penerimaan, tb_pelanggan;
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------------+-------+------------+-------+
| no_servis   | tgl_terima | kode_pelanggan | nama_perangkat | model_perangkat | no_model | keluhan    | kelengkapan | dp     | status    | solusi         | harga | presentase | nama  |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------------+-------+------------+-------+
| SER00000001 | 2019-01-31 | PE000001       | ASUS           | X453SA          | CVT122   | gsdggfddfg | dfgfgd      |   5000 | Di Servis | Belum Diservis |     0 | 15         | Anggi |
| SER00000002 | 2019-02-01 | PE000002       | Sharp          | Aquos           | 305SH    | bootloop   | charger     | 123000 | Di Servis | Belum Diservis |     0 | 15         | Anggi |
| SER00000001 | 2019-01-31 | PE000001       | ASUS           | X453SA          | CVT122   | gsdggfddfg | dfgfgd      |   5000 | Di Servis | Belum Diservis |     0 | 15         | saya  |
| SER00000002 | 2019-02-01 | PE000002       | Sharp          | Aquos           | 305SH    | bootloop   | charger     | 123000 | Di Servis | Belum Diservis |     0 | 15         | saya  |
+-------------+------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------+-----------+----------------+-------+------------+-------+
```

and when i update record show error

```
MariaDB [sijarvis]> UPDATE tb_penerimaan SET no_servis='SER00000002',tgl_terima='2019-02-01',kode_pelanggan='PE000002',nama_perangkat='Sharp',model_perangkat='Aquos',no_model='305sh',keluhan='bootloop',kelengkapan='charger',status='Di Servis',solusi='Instal RAM',harga='15000',presentase='15';
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'SER00000002' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

when in tb_penerimaan there are 1 record, i can update the record.
when in tb_penerimaan there are 2 record or more, there was an error `Duplicate entry 'SER00000002' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint you can't have conflicting values in the same column or set of columns.

Comment: i just update column harga, solusi, and presentase. I did not replace anything except the three columns

Answer (score 0):

In your current Update statement you are trying to update all rows. But that's not possible because `no_servis` has to be unique. Correct would be

```
UPDATE tb_penerimaan SET tgl_terima='2019-02-01', kode_pelanggan='PE000002', nama_perangkat='Sharp', model_perangkat='Aquos', no_model='305sh', keluhan='bootloop', kelengkapan='charger', status='Di Servis', solusi='Instal RAM', harga='15000', presentase='15'
WHERE no_servis = 'SER00000002';
```